# Windows 8 - How to show all users at lock screen

Tags: windows-8, login-screen, lock-screen

There is probably no way to do this but I'll ask anyway.
I have disabled the win8 lock screen so I don't confuse my wife.
When my computer locks it only shows my account at the login screen.

Is there any way to show all users at the login (locked) screen?

I have nothing to hide from my wife so she knows my password and just logs in as me. 
If it showed both users she would login to her own account instead of messing mine up.
I know you can press the back arrow but if I tell the wife she'll get suspicious for no reason, you know how women are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for the lock screen but for the login screen it is possible. But not as simple as it should be.

Follow the instructions on [this page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/force-windows-8-to-show-all-user-accounts-on-the-sign-on-screen/).

It involves changing the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\UserSwitch`. (setting `Enabled` to 1)

The problem is this change does not survive at the moment a user logs in. So there are also  instructions to change this value after every login with a batch file and the Task Scheduler.

The batchfile should be like:

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows|CurrentVersion|Authentication\LogonUI\UserSwitch /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Run this file with a task in the Task Manager "at log on" of "every user".

Exact steps (with screenshots) are at [this page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/force-windows-8-to-show-all-user-accounts-on-the-sign-on-screen/).

---

**Edit**:
I found a way to do the same when you get the lock-screen in case of inactivity.

I discovered that when you disconnect with "Remote Desktop" you get the full-Switch-User-screen with **all** users. You can simulate this with the command `tsdiscon.exe`. We work from there... (You can test this command manually)

Now create a normal-"scheduled task", name it `Switchusers`. In the trigger-tab set a trigger on `On workstation lock`. In the action-tab set an action to run `tsdiscon.exe`. Press Ok.

Now, whenever you get the lockscreen, `tsdiscon.exe` is executed and you get your full-switch-users ;)

If for some reason this doesn't work you can also create the same task with trigger `On idle` and set the `Start the task only if the computer is idle for` on you desired idle-time and `Wait for idle for` on `Do not wait` and check `Stop if the computer ceases to be idle` (or else you'll get multiple login-screens after longer time-outs)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this works if I sign out but not when the computer locks after inactivity.

Comment: Yep, this method is only for after logging out. As far as i know the lock screen can't be changed to show all users. (Although Windows 7, and perhaps 8 too, gives all users after disconnecting a remote desktop, it does not after locking the screen, so perhaps this deserves further investigation to trick Windows in thinking a remote session has terminated). I thought you disabled the lock-screen but i guess it still appears after the time-out/inactivity.

Comment: I found a way. You can execute `tsdiscon.exe` (which is what "Remote Desktop" uses) which will give you the "Switch-users"-screen with **all** users. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 different accounts, then I updated the wrong driver tried to do the System restore, it failed, I booted in safe mode, deleted the driver, and everything seemed to be back to normal.

Not sure which of these steps resulted in only showing my account for the logging in, which was strange assuming I checked accounts and her account was there, I even created a new test account, it didn't showed either, I've set it up as Administrator, and tried almost every of possible solution available on the internet. I was even thinking of making a 'PC Refresh'.

[Then I found this.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/windows-7-welcome-screen-doesnt-display-user/64be1788-6b4d-43f4-b999-5ab85847e694)

In case this URL won't work I'm listing the steps here:

Create a Restore point before these actions so you know your registry is backed up.

1. Open regedit
2. Press Windows+R
3. Type regedit + enter
4. Navigate to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList] You will probably want to right-click
   on “ProfileList” and click export to save the entire subtree in case
   something goes wrong.
5. You will find several subfolders or “keys” named something like
   “S-1-x-xx…”, open them one at the time.
6. Each should contain at least the three value-sets, “Flags”,
   “ProfileImagePath” and “State”, some will contain more
7. Look at the end of ProfileImagePath for the name of the user
   represented by the key You will usually have one for each user on the
   system, and one for each of the three system entries ‘systemprofile’,
   ‘LocalService’ and ’NetworkService’
8. Delete any key (i.e. the whole “S-1-x-xx” folder) that does not
   contain at least those three values. Also delete any empty key named
   default.
9. The welcome screen should now work as expected,
   showing the avatar for all registered users; enjoy!